# Set dynamically checkbox's id property at .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I want to set checkbox's id attribute dynamically as you see below. 
There will be another controls that put that checkbox' right side, also via data binding. Can i do that way? Or can you any suggestion?

```
<% System.Data.DataTable dt = getData_SAPApp();
foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows) { %>
   var valueID = <%=dr["id"].ToString()%>;
   <asp:CheckBox ID=valueID Text='<%=dr["AppName"].ToString()%>' runat="server" />
<% }%>
```